# Dense sets in space of continous functions in C[0,1]

Tags: functional-analysis

Show $$S=[f \in C[0,1]: \int_{0}^{1}f(x)dx=5]$$ is not dense  subset in C[0 1] ww.r.t. sup-norm.

I think i have to take a point in C[0 1] then there should be the corresponding sequence of points in S which must converge to that said point but i am unable to prove, any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** If $\| f-g\|_\infty <\epsilon$ then 
$$\left| \int_0^1 f(t) dt -\int_0^1 g(t) dt \right| <\epsilon$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: there is no sequence in $S$  converging to  $f=0 \in C[0,1]$ (uniformly convergence)

Answer (score 0):

(1). If $X$ is a normed linear space and $S\subset X$ then $Y$ is dense in $X$ iff $v+S=\{v+y:y\in S\}$ is dense in $X$ for every $v\in X.$

(2). Let $v_1(x)=-5$ for all $x\in [0,1].$ So $S$ is dense in $C[0,1]$ iff $v_1+S=\{f\in C[0,1]:\int_0^1 f(x)dx=0\}$ is dense.

(3). The function $\psi(f)=\int_0^1f(x)dx$ is Lipschitz-continous   on $C[0,1].$ because $|\psi(f-g)|\leq \int_0^1|f(x)-g(x)|dx\leq \int_0^1\|f-g\|dx=\|f-g\|.$

(4). Referring to (2), the set $v_1+S=\psi^{-1}\{0\}$ is  closed in $C[0,1]$ because $\psi:C[0,1]\to \mathbb R $ is continuous. If $v_1+S$ were closed and dense it would be equal to  $C[0,1]$. But obviously $\psi^{-1}\{0\} \ne C[0,1]$.